# Django collectstatic giving no errors. But staticfiles not loading on website. Files on S3. project on Lambda with Zappa

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

**Intro:** I have made my application in Django I am trying to get my static and media files hosted in aws s3. My Django project is on `AWS Lambda` and `AWS Api gateway` using `Zappa`.  below is my settings.py

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.MediaStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("ACCESS_SECRET_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.StaticStorage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_S3_DOMAIN = "%s.s3.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s.static/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.media/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I then created a file in my project folder the same as my manage.py called `aws_storage_classes.py`

Below are the contents of my file `aws_storage_classes.py`

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage    

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
```

**Below are my `urls`**

```
if settings.DEBUG:

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also in my settings.py

> **DEBUG = False**

When I do `python manage.py collectstatic` all the staticfiles are downloaded and I don't get any errors. But when go on admin page the static files are not uploaded. See images below

> Below is the image of my S3 bucket

[image]

> Below is what is inside the static folder

[image]

> Static files not loading

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://<bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com/static/style.css?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJHJGHJGJGJGJJGJGJMHIFQ&amp;Signature=yfS3%2BvA0q15aUxw7OBySuQWZfjg%3D&amp;x-amz-security-token=FQoGZXIvYXdgljdaksfgdjsgfkjertert;hre;thtires=151232173">
```

> Updated settings.py

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.MediaStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("ACCESS_SECRET_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.StaticStorage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_S3_DOMAIN = "%s.s3.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s.static/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.media/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Below is the link after adding `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://django-static-media.s3.amazonaws.com/static/style.css?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAGGGGGGGGGMHIFQ&amp;Signature=6gFQTsOSDFSDFA%3D&amp;x-amz-security-token=FQoGZvwbJhd9amp;Expires=1549168642">`

Comment: Do the static files display when you set DEBUG=True?

Comment: @ThomasMyers No they do not

Comment: Did you clear cache? Check the path of static files using view page source in chrome or firefox? It should be something like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.XXXXX.css"> if so can you share the path please.

Comment: @ThomasMyers I have added that link above

Comment: your files are uploaded in 'static' folder but in the settings u r trying to access these files using 'staticfiles' folder. Please change in aws from static to staticfiles or in your code change staticfiles to static.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your url should be /static/admin/style.css/.... to fix this add the following to your settings.py file.

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

Comment: no that dint do it. I have added the change that I made to the code above + I restarted my server

Comment: DId it change the url? Just confirm that you put <bucketname> in the url and that is not what it is actually showing.

Comment: No I just did not add the bucket name here for security reasons. The link has the bucket name

Comment: Ok just wanted to make sure we were on the same page. Make sure you run collect static again after the changes.

Comment: I have added the new link with the code to above question

Comment: running collect static now dint do that before

Comment: No my friend. The `collectstatic` gave the below result `0 static files copied, 124 unmodified.` Rest everything was the same. I even emailed the link to my host computer and tried on a virgin browser. still not loading static. Also restarted my server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187800/discussion-between-thomas-myers-and-marcobianchi).